# Can the Microsoft bot framework access the Slack web API methods?

Tags: slack-api, botframework

Is there a way for the Microsoft bot framework to get access to the web API methods in the Slack API (channel read for example)?

Answer (score 1):

If your bot needs access to Slack specific APIs, it should call the Slack API directly using the bot credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) that Slack provided when you created the app.  Going through BotFramework would add additional hops making your bot less performant.

Comment: But if I want to distribute my bot to many users wont they each have to have an additional signup step when the install the bot? DO you have any examples of anyone doing this? thx Any articles on something like this?

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking.  The credentials are those for your bot, not your end users.  Each end user would need to add the bot to their slack channel, but that's true for any bot.  What additional sign up step are you thinking is needed?

Comment: @Lars, as far as I can see, there's a problem with this approach: you can't access Slack API with Client ID/Secret, you have to exchange them for token. And that is done by Microsoft Bot connector, which, in turn, stores the token somewhere inside, making the communication between bot and Slack transparent - so the bot can't see the token and can't use it to access Slack.

Comment: That shouldn't prevent you from calling the Slack API with Client ID/Secret yourself and exchanging for your own token.